# Tracking the same event with different mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I am trying to figure out what is the best way of tracking file downloads (specifically, pdf files) in my webpage by using Google Analytics (UA). I know that with

```
<a href="book.pdf" onClick="ga('send','event','PDF Downloads','Click','Book');">Download Book</a>
```

I can track those events triggered by a (left) click on the link. How to track this same event but for right-click and middle-click actions? I am not interested in separating the event by types of click, but just want to have a more accurate measure of how many times the file was downloaded.

My first attempt to this problem was to use `oncontextmenu` and `auxclick` for right and middle click, respectively. So I would end up with something like:

```html
<a href="book.pdf" onClick="ga('send','event','PDF Downloads','Click','Book');"
             oncontextmenu="ga('send','event','PDF Downloads','Click','Book');"
                  auxclick="ga('send','event','PDF Downloads','Click','Book');">
                  Download Book</a>
```

But repeating `ga('send','event','PDF Downloads','Click','Book');` three times seems very messy and prone to errors. What would be the best way of implementing this?

Ps. How good is `auxclick` to track middle click events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '.track', function(e){
  //e.which  1 = left click,  2 = middle click, 3 = right click
  
  //track by book url (http://example.com/book.pdf)
  ga('send', 'event', 'PDF Downloads', 'Click', this.href);
  
  //track by book title (Book Title 2)
  ga('send', 'event', 'PDF Downloads', 'Click', $(this).data('book'));

  //track by button contents (Download Book 2)
  ga('send', 'event', 'PDF Downloads', 'Click', $(this).text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="book.pdf" class="track" data-book="Book Title 1">Download Book 1</a>

<a href="book.pdf" class="track" data-book="Book Title 2">Download Book 2</a>
```

Comment: Would this require defining a new class for every file I want to track? For example, if I have `book1.pdf` and `book2.pdf` (or more) with labels `Book1` and `Book 2`, how to make this more general? Is it really important to use the `target="_blank"` attribute?

Comment: @Lord_77 the last argument in the ga() call is where you would add your book title or url. i'll update the code to make this more generalized. target="_blank" shouldn't be needed for download links, but if that links goes to another website, that would likely happen before the ga() event can track the visit.